# Facebook processing error in android

Tags: android, facebook

When I start apps then it's crashed. I follow this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

My Error:

```
10-19 07:19:32.176: W/dalvikvm(2607): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
10-19 07:19:32.176: W/dalvikvm(2607): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
10-19 07:19:32.176: W/dalvikvm(2607): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
10-19 07:19:32.226: W/dalvikvm(2607): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
10-19 07:19:32.226: I/dalvikvm(2607): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
10-19 07:19:32.226: W/dalvikvm(2607): VFY: unable to resolve static method 248: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
10-19 07:19:32.226: D/dalvikvm(2607): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
10-19 07:19:32.336: D/AndroidRuntime(2607): Shutting down VM
10-19 07:19:32.336: W/dalvikvm(2607): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1570)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:977)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:1132)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:1017)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.example.facebookfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-19 07:19:32.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2607):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager`**

Check the Properties of the FacebookSDK and make sure it contains the **`android-supportv4`** library. If it is not, add it to the build path of the FacebookSDK.